# Logged in users cannot store visualizations within their OpenSearch tenant space

Tags: database

We have recently switched 1 of our 3 clusters from Elasticsearch to OpenSearch. The cluster is receiving data into 30+ data streams and the data is searchable in Dashboards using index patterns etc. using an admin user. The cluster has about 10 tenants and each tenant has a role connected to it with backend mapping to LDAP. This seems to be working fine.

However, when a regular user logs in and chooses a tenant they cannot see any index patterns, and they cannot create any index patterns. If I give the role read access to the `.opensearch_dashboards` alias, then the user is able to see all the index patterns created by the admin users and can use those they have access to through the roles, to search, but is still not able to save visualizations/dashboards they have created to disk.

I refuse to give each role write access to the `.opensearch_dashboards` alias and its indices unless I find documentation describing this as the intended solution. I have not tried this solution, so I do not even know if it will work.

I am used to pre-creating the index patterns the spaces in Elasticsearch/Kibana should have access to and I am trying to do the same in OpenSearch for its tenants. I also assume this problem exist because of me and I, not understanding OpenSearch as well as I do Elasticsearch.

An example tenant, role and mapping.

```yaml
GET _plugins/_security/api/tenants/Students%20Admins
{
  "Students Admins": {
    "reserved": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "description": "Tenant for the Student administrators at <university>",
    "static": false
  }
}

GET _plugins/_security/api/roles/Students%20Admin
{
  "Students Admin": {
    "reserved": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "cluster_permissions": [],
    "index_permissions": [
      {
        "index_patterns": [
          "logs-*-students"
        ],
        "dls": "",
        "fls": [],
        "masked_fields": [],
        "allowed_actions": [
          "read"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "tenant_permissions": [
      {
        "tenant_patterns": [
          "Student Admins"
        ],
        "allowed_actions": [
          "kibana_all_write"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "static": false
  }
}

GET _plugins/_security/api/rolesmapping/Students%20Admin
{
  "Students Admin": {
    "hosts": [],
    "users": [],
    "reserved": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "backend_roles": [
      "<Group in LDAP>"
    ],
    "and_backend_roles": []
  }
}
```

In the role, there are no cluster permissions, but I tried playing around with cluster_composite_ops and cluster_composite_ops_ro (replacement for the read permissions on the .opensearch_dashboards alias), but that did not work either.

Opensearch config that might be relevant.

```yaml
plugins.security.system_indices.enabled: true
plugins.security.system_indices.indices: [".plugins-ml-model", ".plugins-ml-task", ".opendistro-alerting-config", ".opendistro-alerting-alert*", ".opendistro-anomaly-results*", ".opendistro-anomaly-detector*", ".opendistro-anomaly-checkpoints", ".opendistro-anomaly-detection-state", ".opendistro-reports-*", ".opensearch-notifications-*", ".opensearch-notebooks", ".opensearch-observability", ".ql-datasources", ".opendistro-asynchronous-search-response*", ".replication-metadata-store", ".opensearch-knn-models"]
```

Dashboards config that might be relevant.

```yaml
# I changed the password for kibanaserver at bootstrap time.
opensearch.username: "kibanaserver"
opensearch_security.multitenancy.enabled: true
opensearch_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: [Private, Global]
opensearch_security.readonly_mode.roles: [kibana_read_only]
```

Internal user definition

```yaml
kibanaserver:
  hash: "<NEW HASH>"
  reserved: true
  description: "Opensearch Dashboards system user"
```

Internal roles definition

```yaml
# Restrict users so they can only view visualization and dashboard on OpenSearchDashboards
kibana_read_only:
  reserved: true
```

Is the role missing something to be allowed to see and write objects within its own tenant?
Have i configured OpenSearch-Dashboards wrong so that it is read only somehow unless you're an admin?

I have observed that when logged in as an administrator, no matter which tenant is active, I see all the index patterns created in the system. I do not know if that is intended or not. Just mentioning it in case it has importance.

Any idea how I can give my users write access to their tenant space, and if possible, only see the index patterns defined within their own tenant?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. When creating a role which contains users which will be logging into OpenSearch Dashboards, the user need to be a member of the kibana_user role too. This will solve the issue I mentioned above except for all the index patterns being visible in Discovery for all users.

In other words. Whatever backendrole you add to a role which is connected to a tenant. That backendrole also needs to be added as a backend role for the kibana_user role.

Log in, log out and everything is fixed.

```
GET _plugins/_security/api/rolesmapping/Students%20Admin
{
  "Students Admin": {
    "hosts": [],
    "users": [],
    "reserved": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "backend_roles": [
      "<Group in LDAP>"
    ],
    "and_backend_roles": []
  }
}

GET _plugins/_security/api/rolesmapping/kibana_user
{
  "kibana_user": {
    "hosts": [],
    "users": [],
    "reserved": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "backend_roles": [
      "kibanauser",
      "<Group in LDAP>"
    ],
    "and_backend_roles": []
  }
}
```